# Data is not mapped after update to useState - React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I use useEffect to trigger a function called, callCards.

This makes an api request and retrieves data.

I can see that the api request retrieves data, and I can even see that changeCards changes the data for fetchedCards, however, the data in return does not re map with the new data.

I know that the new data exists at that point, because I can console log right above the map and see that it's there.

For whatever reason, it seems like the data does not want to remap once the state has been changed for fetchedCards.

However, I also use this function onScroll when a user scrolls to the bottom of the page.

When this happens, the function is called, the data is rendered, mapped, and shows correctly.

```
PlayerPage = (props) => {
    const [fetchedCards, changeCards] = useState([])
    const [currentUser, updateUser] = useState('')
    const [skip, setSkip] = useState(0)
    const [load, setLoad] = useState(false)


    callCards = (passedSkip) => {

            let requestParams =
                props.player ?
                `players=${props.player}&startDate=2019-03-20T03:10:43.990Z&sort=createdAt`:
                props.team ?
                `team=${props.team}&startDate=2019-03-20T03:10:43.990Z&sort=createdAt` :
                props.league ?
                `league=${props.league}&startDate=2019-03-20T03:10:43.990Z&sort=createdAt`:
                null

            let finalSkip = skip === 0 ? skip : passedSkip
            console.log(`http://${BASE}:4000/reports?${requestParams}&skip=${finalSkip}`)
            axios.get(`http://${BASE}:4000/reports?${requestParams}&skip=${finalSkip}`)
                .then(response => {


                        let combinedCards = fetchedCards
                        combinedCards.push(...response.data)

                        console.log(combinedCards)
                        changeCards(combinedCards)
                        setLoad(false)

                })

    }

    getMoreCards = (e) => {
        var windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height,
            height = e.nativeEvent.contentSize.height,
            offset = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
        if( windowHeight + offset >= height && load !== true ){
            setLoad(true)
            setSkip(skip + 2)
            callCards(skip + 2)
        }
    }


    useEffect(() =>{
        callCards(0)
    }, [])

    return(
        <View>
        {console.log(fetchedCards)}
        <View>
            <Header
                rounded
            >
                <View>
                    <NativeText
                        onPress={() => {
                            Actions.pop()  
                        }}

                        style ={{color: '#006FFF', fontSize: 12, fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular'}}
                    >
                        Back
                    </NativeText>
                </View>
                </Header>
                </View>
        <ScrollView
            style={{backgroundColor: 'white', height: '100%'}}
            onScroll={e=> getMoreCards(e)}
            scrollEventThrottle={16}
        >
        <View style={{position: 'relative', paddingTop: '3%', paddingBottom: '35%'}} >
        { 
            fetchedCards !== '' ?
            fetchedCards.map((v,i) => {
                return(
                <View key={i}>
                        <Text
                            style={{color: '#58395C'}}>{v.player.player_name} - </Text>
                </View>
                )
            })
        : null
        }
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
</View>
    )
}

export default PlayerPage
```

Comment: Can you create a codepen for that ?

Comment: Try `changeCards(latest=>([...latest,...response.data]))` instead of creating combinedCards from not updated fetchedCards.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are mutating the array.

You need to do this instead:

```
let combinedCards = [...fetchedCards]
combinedCards.push(response.data)
console.log(combinedCards)
changeCards(combinedCards)
```

(or just do)

```
let combinedCards = [...fetchedCards, response.data]
```